# If Else statement breaks because variable doesn't always exist

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-tag-manager

I am creating a custom javascript variable in Google Tag Manager that SHOULD register specific button clicks and pass back another field/title text as a variable.

The issue with the code that I am finding below is that the mapButtonText variable doesn't always exist (you have to click on the map icon for it to exist) until then when I go to the developers console in chrome and look for mapButtonText all I get returned is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at <anonymous>:1:124`

Also, when the else if statement reaches the mapButtonText condition it breaks the entire if else statement (meaning even the first statement won't return the correct value anymore).

```
function(){
  
  var formButtonText = document.querySelector("#locationSelect > button").innerText;
  var formSelectedLocation = document.querySelector('#locationID option').innerText;
  var mapButtonText = document.querySelector("#map > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.infoWindow > a").innerText;
  var mapSelectedLocation = document.querySelector('.infoWindow:hover h3').innerText;
  var clickLocationName;
  var clickElementText = {{Click Text}};

  if (clickElementText === formButtonText){
    clickLocationName = formSelectedLocation;
  }
  else if (clickElementText === mapButtonText){
    clickLocationName = mapSelectedLocation;
  }
  else {clickLocationName = "No Location Selected";}

  return clickLocationName;

}
```

I have tested excluding the else if line and the code works fine (see code below)

```
function(){
  
  var formButtonText = document.querySelector("#locationSelect > button").innerText;
  var formSelectedLocation = document.querySelector('#locationID option').innerText;
  var mapButtonText = document.querySelector("#map > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.infoWindow > a").innerText;
  var mapSelectedLocation = document.querySelector('.infoWindow:hover h3').innerText;
  var clickLocationName;
  var clickElementText = {{Click Text}};

  if (clickElementText === formButtonText){
    clickLocationName = formSelectedLocation;
  }
  else {clickLocationName = "No Location Selected";}

  return clickLocationName;

}
```

What am I missing in the else if statement to make the first piece of code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to just do a simple check to see if your element exists. In this example, if it does not exist I have set some default text. The default could also be set to blank or null depending on your logic needs.

```
   element = document.querySelector('your_selector');
   var some_variable = element ? element.innerText : 'some_default_text';
```

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right course. The issue ended up being that because the map elements sometimes arent there they were screwing up the logic of the entire statement. When I added a couple of variables to check whether they were there are not it took care of the entire problem.